# Unit testing an asynchronous service in angularjs

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, asynchronous, angularjs

I am trying to unit test a service which has asynchronous methods but am having no luck.

I have tried to implement with promises by using the $q support in angularjs.

Any help would be appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/9pBze/37/

```
angular.module('myapp', ['myservice']);

angular.module('myservice', []).factory('myservice', function($q) {
  var ls = {};

  ls.DoIt = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    setTimeout(function(){
        deferred.resolve(5);
    },3000);

    return deferred.promise;
  }

  return ls;

});

describe('services', function () {

    beforeEach(module('myservice'));

    it("should equal 2",  inject(function(myservice) {
        myservice.DoIt().then(function(returned) {
            expect(returned).toEqual(2);
        });        
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 30):

First of all, the `setTimeout` is particularly tricky to test since it hard to mock. Fortunately AngularJS has a wrapper around it (`$timeout`) that plays the same role but can be easily mocked:

```
  ls.DoIt = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $timeout(function(){
        deferred.resolve(5);
    },3000);

    return deferred.promise;
  }
```

The mock provided for `$timeout` allows us to easily simulate elapsed time (with `$timeout.flush()`) which means our tests can run fast, without really waiting for the async event to complete (please note that the production code is still using async API!).

The changed tests would look like:

```
it("should equal 5",  inject(function(myservice, $timeout) {

    var valueToVerify;
    myservice.DoIt().then(function(returned) {
      valueToVerify = returned;  
    });  
    $timeout.flush();        
    expect(valueToVerify).toEqual(5);
}));
```

And finally the working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v9L9G/1/

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. The service I am writing uses IndexedDB and the api is asynchronous and I am struggling as to how I can apply the above when the DoIt function would call something like request.onsuccess = function(event) {
  // Do something with request.result!
  deferred.resolve(result);
};

Comment: @Pawel What if I'm testing a controller which uses `DoIt` mock service, and inside that controller, `DoIt` is in a loop, so it gets called multiple times. How do I flush it multiple times? Isn't it possible to get `DoIt` to flush itself? I tried to get an asynchronous mock to flush itself by including [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cUEQ8/) in it, but that doesn't seem very robust.

Comment: Actually, the fiddle I shared above seems to successfully get a mock to flush itself. The problem I was having turned out to be some where else...

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource How do we test that `valueToVerify` was still undefined after 1000ms?

Answer (score 4):

It's not related to Angular itself, but to [Jasmine async tests](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support).

If you need a `setTimeout` use Angular [`$timeout`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$timeout). And if you wish to have a fine control over setTimeout/$timeout executions, use [mocked Clock](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/#section-Mocking_the_JavaScript_Clock).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will review the $timeout documentation.

Comment: The provided link to the Jasmine Async 404ed. I reckon it is now http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support