# How to let an angular $http call time out in an unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs

How to make an AngularJS `$http` call time out in an unit test so I can test my code behavior in case of network timeouts? I've found nothing in `$httpBackend` object, also experimenting with `$timeout` itself didn't yield results. My tested code uses `$http` to make requests and `$timeout` to schedule retries, although I think it's not relevant as I can't force a single call to timeout.

The code that demonstrates the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/5xE8d/5/

Comment: `it's not relevant as I can't force a single call to timeout.` why?

Comment: Looks like a pull request on angular-mocks.js is in your future.

Comment: @MaximShoustin: Because I don't know how to do it. `$timeout(function({ //continue test here }), time_to_wait);` does not work, for example.

Comment: see this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477370/unit-testing-an-asynchronous-service-in-angularjs

Comment: that one doesn't use $http. I updated my question to link a jsfiddle.

Comment: `$timeout` in tests is also mocked out.

Answer (score 0):

I am aware that this answer does not really directly answer the question as asked, but might solve the problem.

"Letting the `$http` time out" tests the wrong thing. Your jsFiddle directly tests *that* the timeout happens *after your configured time*. That is not a unit test.

The functionality you are testing through that is that `$http` works correctly in that it triggers error callbacks after the configured time. `$http` however is not the *system under test*.

As a rule of thumb, for a unit test you should assume that dependencies work as specified. You should assume that the $http service triggers the error callback after the time you configure.

This reduces the problem to these two tests:

- Ensure you configure the timout correctly for the call, and
- ensure that your callback performs the correct actions.

If you insist on making sure that the integration of the `$http` dependency and your code works correctly, that would belong into an integration test, or in the angular world an [E2E test](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.e2e-testing).

Otherwise you can mock out $http and check that the arguments you receive have `timeout: 5000` set on them. For the other case you can again mock $http and capture the callback you give to `error()`, calling that directly in your test.