# How to test promise in angularjs

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine

I've come across a case where I simply can't make the test passed.

Here is the test:

```
it('should accept an fucntion run it immediately', inject(function($rootScope, ready) {
    var spy = jasmine.createSpy('ready').andCallFake(function(){
        console.log("I'm ready");
    });
    ready.done(spy);
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

Here is code:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('ready', function($q, _, $rootScope){

    var defer = $q.defer();

    //in real case it's actually calling 3rd party code, so no $timeout
    _.defer(function(){
        $rootScope.$apply(function(){
            defer.resolve();
        });
    });

    return {
        done: function(fn){
            defer.promise.then(fn);
        }
    };
});
```

The log of `I'm ready` did appeared but the test still failed. So I think its just the problem of handling async flow in `jasmine`. But I can't think of to test it using jasmine's `runs` and `waitsFor`.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477370/unit-testing-an-asynchronous-service-in-angularjs

Comment: A possibly simplification: why not just return `defer.promise` from the factory? Then the calling code can use `ready.then(function() {...})`, otherwise you're going into slightly back towards callback-hell.

Comment: @MichalCharemza that would be good too

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the test is failing, and then the console.log appears, in that order, as the promise isn't resolved until after the `_.defer` has called its callback, which is after the current call stack is cleared.

What you need is a way to force the underscore/lodash `_.defer`, to call its callback/promises, so your promise in the factory gets resolved immediately. If you were using `$timeout`, you could call `$timeout.flush()` in the test, but as far as I know underscore/lodash doesn't have anything like this.

However, before the test, you should be able to inject a mock '_', with a defer function, that calls its callback immediately:

```
beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
  $provide.value('_', {
    'defer': function(callback) {callback()};
  });    
}));
```

In your real case, you would need to do something like the above, by injecting a mock 3rd party service and forcing it to complete, so your promise gets resolved before the `expect` call in the test.

If for some reason you can't inject a mock version of the 3rd party code, you can make the test asynchronous, as explained at http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/#section-Asynchronous_Support, but this should be avoided if possible, as it makes the test runs slower.

Comment: It only works if I add a $rootScope.$apply() before expect check.

Comment: You're right! I had just [made this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LPsuH5I6J0BsjRVdKEvD?p=preview) to work that out

Comment: dear @MichalCharemza I am struggling with the similar issue, but cant figure it out. Can you please check this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27921918/how-to-test-defer-using-jasmine-angularjs